# Can I perform a RAID-1 Setup on Linux over an existing disk one containing data?

Tags: linux, raid1

I have the following setup on my Fileserver:

- 2 HDDs In intel RST RAID-1 containing Windows OS+DATA

And I want to migrate into the following configuration:

- 1 SSD containing CentOS 8
- 2 HDDS containing data only in RAID-1 configuration

The RAID-1 will use the Linux Kernel mdam instead intel RST. But because it will take some time once I receive the second HDD, so far I will set up my file server like this:

- 1 SSD containing CentOs
- 1 HDD containing Data

So once I backed up my data I will format the remaining HDD and then restore the data on it using a live USB and afterwards I will install my OS on SSD. But because data restoration will take some time I want to avoid a data restoration once I receive my second HDD.

So can I setup a RAID-1 using `madm` on my Linux server without losing any data, or I will need to re-store the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a single disk Linux (CentOS in the example) system into a two disk RAID1 system without loosing data or reinstall the system, but the procedure may seem rather complex. The raid will be a linux software raid managed by “mdadm”.

Basically, you will have to:

- Create a single-disk RAID-1 array with our new disk
- Move all your data from the old-disk to the new RAID-1 array
- Verify the data move was successful
- Wipe the old disk and add it to the new RAID-1 array

[Here's one strategy and the steps to do so](https://supporthost.in/create-convert-to-raid1-setup-on-existing-centos7-4-system/).

If that looks bad, better wait for the HDD and make the RAID from start. Since there can be trouble across all the steps, I'd recommend waiting if you're not a Linux expert.

Comment: So it is a good idea to just create a single disk raid1 first and then I am just ready to slap on any extra disks right?

Comment: It simplifies things, yes. You basically skip some steps later on.

Comment: Just to add, since you plan has a backup of your data before doing the job, everything should be fine.